# QueryDSL: Rationale behind SQLUpdateClause ignoring nulls by default

Tags: java, querydsl

I came across an issue while updating a field with a null value using QueryDsl.

The following code for example:

```
entity.setText(null);
new SQLUpdateClause(connection, templates, QEntity )
    .where(...)
    .populate(entity)
    .execute();
```

silently ignores the update on the "text" field.

Digging in the code I figure out a way to properly set null values with:

```
entity.setText(null);
new SQLUpdateClause(connection, templates, QEntity )
    .where(...)
    .populate(entity, DefaultMapper.WITH_NULL_BINDINGS)
    .execute();
```

This causes a couple issues:

- Silent bugs: Forgetting to update the mapper can lead to bugs hard to find later on, because the update doesn't throw an exception.
- API duplication: One need to add an "updateNulls" flag to an existing updateEntity API, in order to maintain compatibility.

What is the rationale behind the decision to ignore update nulls by default?
Would throwing an exception break the exising API?

Answer (score 0):

It makes life really easy on insert statements.

When processing updates, simply retrieve the original record, make the necessary changes and then use the DefaultMapper.WITH_NULL_BINDINGS to 'upsert' the modified record.